# No supported translation to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

We have this code:

```
private IList<InfoRequest> GetBy(Func<InformationRequest, string> func, string searchby)
{
    var requests = _dc.InformationRequests
                      .Where(x => func.Invoke(x).Contains(searchby))
                      .OrderBy(y => y.RequestDate);

    return Mapper.Map<InformationRequest[], InfoRequest[]>(requests.ToArray());
}
```

It continues to throw the no supported translation to SQL error. Any ideas on the problem or how to resolve it?

Comment: Contains is supported, but your func is not.  Provide some more information about what you are trying to do with Func.  It is your problem.  Linq to SQL can not push an Expression down to the db.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the advice found in this [link](http://www.atrevido.net/blog/2007/09/05/Calling+Custom+Methods+In+LINQtoSQL.aspx),  Convert your func to an expression and that will result in a differnt overloaded .Where method getting called.

```
 private IList<InfoRequest> GetBy(Expression<Func<InformationRequest, string>> exp, string searchby)
 {

      var requests = _dc.InformationRequests
                  .Where(x => exp(x).Contains(searchby))
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that one too. It doesn't give me the option to pass in the InformationRequest. I'd have to do this: .Where(x => exp.Compile().Invoke(x).Contains(searchby))

At that point, it gives the same error as before.

Comment: can you please post your func above?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```
 private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> StartsWith<T>(Func<string, string> func)
{
    var searchBy = func.Method.GetParameters()[0].Name;
    var search = Expression.Constant(func(null), typeof(string));

    var searchByParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), searchBy);
    var searchByExp = Expression.Property(searchByParam, searchBy);

    var methodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });//, typeof(StringComparison)});
    var containsExpression = Expression.Call(searchByExp, methodInfo, search);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsExpression, searchByParam);
}
```

If you want more details, I blogged it here: http://derans.blogspot.com/2010/05/building-l2s-expression-with-net-35.html